# Webpage won't display images

Tags: php, html

I've created a website and I'm using PHP to fetch an Oracle database table.

I've coded the Oracle database table with the correct image file names and uploaded the pictures to a online directory but it's not showing up on the webpage.

This is my code fetching results from the database.

```
<?php


while(oci_fetch_array($stmt)) {

echo("<tr valign=top bgcolor=#ccffcc>");

$fg1 = oci_result($stmt,"TITLE"); //"Title";
echo("<td width=100>");
echo ($fg1);
echo("</td>");
// Aspect value in column two
$fg2 = oci_result($stmt,"AUTHOR");//"Author";
echo("<td width=100>");
echo ($fg2);
echo("</td>");
$fg3 = oci_result($stmt,"PRICE");//"Price";
echo("<td width=75>");
echo ($fg3);
echo("</td>");
$fg4 = oci_result($stmt,"PHOTO");//"Photo";
echo ("<br><img src=http://xxxxxx.kz/home/preznek/public_html/website/search_pics".$fg4."><br>");
echo("</td>");

echo("</tr>");
} 
oci_close($connect); 
?>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does this image really exists `search_pics".$fg4."`?

Comment: No it's the folder with all the pictures. Pictures are names picture1.png etc

Comment: then it need to be `search_pics/".$fg4`

Comment: "search_pics/".$fg4" throws up an error on the webpage

Answer (score 1):

Two problems at a quick glance.

1. Your path is lacking quotation marks (single or double). It should be like this: `<img src="/path/to/image.jpg"/>`
2. The path itself appears to be incorrect. Typically if a directory is named "public_html", it is the *root* directory of your public-facing website. This means your path should be "http://xxxxxx.kz/website/search_pics/filename.jpg".

Answer (score 0):

Try this please,

change this,

```
echo ("<br><img src=http://xxxxxx.kz/home/preznek/public_html/website/search_pics".$fg4."><br>");
```

to this,

```
echo "<br><img src='http://xxxxxx.kz/website/search_pics/".$fg4."'><br>";
```

You really don't need to use `echo ("")` you can just use it like this `echo ""`.
I changed you code this might help you as well

```
<table>
while(oci_fetch_array($stmt)) {
    //Variables
    $fg1 = oci_result($stmt,"TITLE"); //"Title";
    // Aspect value in column two
    $fg2 = oci_result($stmt,"AUTHOR");//"Author";
    $fg3 = oci_result($stmt,"PRICE");//"Price";
    $fg4 = oci_result($stmt,"PHOTO");//"Photo"; ?>

    <tr valign="top" bgcolor="#ccffcc">
    <td width="100">
    <?php echo $fg1;?>
    </td>;

    <td width="100">
    <?php echo $fg2;?>
    </td>

    <td width="75">
    <?php echo $fg3;?>
    </td>
    <td>
        <img src="http://xxxxxx.kz/website/search_pics/<?php echo $fg4?>">
    </td>
    </tr>

 <?php } ?>
</table>
```

Try this and let me know if it works or not.

Comment: Problem with your code. The pictures load correctly but they are above and outside the table. Not sure how to fix it.

Comment: Photos are still outside the table :/ They are sitting on top of the table

Comment: what is the size of your photos width height. It seems the code I've given you is working the issue is your images might be big.

Comment: Width 100 pixels Height 150 pixels

Comment: If there  `<table></table>` tags in that code you're trying ? if not add them.

Comment: Here look at this [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5uveu9t9/1/) I did it might help you to understand what has happened.